# Is Suzaku Kururugi completely oblivious of the Purges of Shinjuku Ghetto and the Saitama Ghetto?

Tags: code-geass

From Episodes 10-13 there is a huge moral guilt bestowed on all the characters. And I find it funny because its from one battle where barely 1% of the casualties experienced from the purges were met.

Suzaku Kururugi wants to fight for Britannia to save his people (or hope they integrate into the system) but is **he aware of what Britannia does to the Elevens?**

Like honestly he thinks what the BKs do are wrong yet hes morally ok with mass executions of children/elderly. Is this explained?

Comment: It's been a while since I saw Code Geass, but I interpreted more as Suzaku being more or less aware of what was going on but believing more in changing things "through the system". I could well be pretty wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is not morally ok with executing people. If you noticed he refused to kill civilians in episode 2,especially since one was his friend, and he saved the falling women in the same episode in the middle of a battlefield. The only time he even actually killed civilians was when he fired the FLEIJA in Tokyo.

He is obviously aware of what the Britannians do as he sees some of it first hand. He is even one of the ones that is discriminated against, which is seen in the episode where he stood around washing paint off of his shirt and in ep 5, even though they can't do anything more than that because he is an honorary Britannian. The only problem is at first he cannot change it. That is why he needed to become the knight of one. From that position he would have the authority to prevent the Britannian's treatment of elevens.

He is not ok with the executions but at the same time he is powerless to prevent them unless he were to become the knight of one.

Comment: the FLEIJA firing was a result of his Geass command to "Live" and the only way for him to live was to fire it. had he not had that command he would have accepted his death